# numpy, summing matrices gives wrong result

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

Why summing together r g b channel matrices together doesn't give maximum result of 765, when every matrix has maximum of 255 and these values are at same position? But it gives maximum of 3 if all matrices are divided by 255.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

pic= Image.open(picture_dir)
r,g,b = pic.split()

g_ = np.asarray(g)
b_ = np.asarray(b)
r_ = np.asarray(r)

print((r_+g_+b_).max()) # gives result of 255, supposed to be 765


g_mat = np.asarray(g)/255
b_mat = np.asarray(b)/255
r_mat = np.asarray(r)/255

print((g_mat+b_mat+r_mat).max()) # gives result of 3.0
```

Does subdividing (like here : np.asarray(g)/255) actually changes anything other than value?

**EDIT:** dtype before dividing is uint8 and after dividing float64

Comment: My assumption here is that you're creating some sort of data structure containing each of the three values, rather than summing them. And max is just returning the largest value in that data structure.

Comment: I know that they are at same position, because I edited that picture to have same values, or in other words i just made some parts white.

Comment: If `r_`, `g_` and `b_` have dtype uint8, then so does `r_ + g_ + b_`, and if an element is 255 in all three, the sum will be 253.

Answer (score 1):

Try examining the type of g_,b_, and r_.

If they have type numpy.uint8, you should get a warning and the result should be 253.

In the second case, the g_mat, b_mat and r_mat are converted to numpy.int64 upon division

Comment: He is dividing by an integer value so if the array is `uint8`, it will not be converted to floating point during division.

Comment: I never said float.The result get converted to numpy.int64 and you will most likely get the result 3. In the first case, you get an overflow and therefore 255 (I got 253 for some reason)

Comment: Yeah, I think this is the issue (the type being `uint8`, I mean).  If the OP switches to an `int` dtype, e.g. `r_ = np.asarray(r_, int)`, it should work.

Comment: My mistake - you wrote "int64" and I mistakenly thought "float64".

Comment: So summing up together several uint8 matrices will give always another uint8 dtype matrix (and upper limit of 255)?